# How to modify compilerOptions.lib in TypeScript Playground?

Tags: typescript, typescript-playground

I have a function named `filterNil`:

```js
export function filterNil<T extends object>(obj: T): NonNullable<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => ![null, undefined, ''].includes(v)));
}
```

The `Object.fromEntries` throws a TS type error:

> Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2019' or later.(2550)

The error message is clear, How can I add `es2019` lib to `compilerOptions.lib` option in TypeScript Playground?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWMwGxmCgDkCAeAFTlCJQBMBnOCAIwCtgMA+ACjfYAuOJQCUwkjhJJ8+AIat8wKtzgBvAFBw4UYDCRRcAeQ5cYAOgRQIAWwCiKGFEzBGvE5wzngj56-4copYERFC8vADaAPoANHAAbgC6onAAvKoAhBEoMvhxqPTACJgowPRxAOQVieYlaPhIhW7xoq0A3BoAvkA)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the playground chooses what library declarations to include based on the target.

If you change `Target:` to `es2019` or later it works.

Description from the TS config menu:

> Target:
> Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations.

Answer (score 1):

CLick on `TS Config` and then select a `Target`

[image]

Comment: I found this. Is there no way to modify the `lib` configuration? Is this by design?

Comment: Seems that it is impossible or I just don't know ho to do it. You better ask @orta on twitter